# How to debug an event listener in Firebug?

Tags: javascript, firebug

I would like to execute every code step by step after the `debugger` keyword in Firebug. In the following example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZQEJ/194/) the execution halts when the form is clicked because of the `debugger` keyword in the *onclick* attribute. Subsequently I click *Step Into* in Firebug but instead of showing the jQuery code, it shows nothing... How to make Firebug halt at the jQuery code?

```
<form method="get" onclick="debugger">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Search Google">
</form>
```

jQuery code:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    document.title = "How to shown this line in debugger?";
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to search Google?');
});
```

Comment: yes, i clicked Step Into too, all it show is "debugger" word instead of showing  document.title = "How to shown this line in debugger?";

Comment: because that is where you have `debugger`, if you want to debug the callback function put `debugger` inside it

Comment: @PatrickEvans sorry about the question.. in the above example i can add *debugger*, but i can do that in other websites :(

Comment: Just use Chrome :-) It has pause-on-next-event built in

Comment: @JanDvorak i am unable to find that option in Google Chrome (its the latest version)

Comment: sources => click the "pause" button

Comment: Regarding Jan's comment: Firebug has similar abilities within its [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) (added in version 2.0).

Comment: Note that when you place the `debugger` keyword inside the click event handler, you'll just be able to debug that event handler. What you want to debug, though, is the completely unrelated *submit* event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Firebug**

1. Go to the [*Script* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Panel)

   [image]
2. Click the dropdown for the scripts and select the script you need

   [image]
3. Add a breakpoint on the line you want to start debugging from

   [image]

**For Chrome**

1. Go to the console
2. Then to the Sources tab

   [image]
3. Click "show navigator" button

   [image]
4. Select the script
5. Click the line number you wish to debug from

   [image]